# A question about a correspondence of the primes of $A(X)$ contained in $m_P$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Here $X$ is an affine variety in $\mathbb A^n$. $p$ is a point in $\mathbb A^n$. I can't see why there is a 1-1 correspondence between the primes of $A(X)$ contained in $m_P$ and the closed subvarieties of $X$ containing $P$. I wonder why it's not *irreducible* closed subvarieties of $X$ containing $P$?

Comment: A lot of people (myself included) take "variety" to mean irreducible unless there's a good reason to believe otherwise. In the first formulation one would have to look at all radical ideals of $A(X)$.

Comment: @Hoot Thank you very much.